# passing parameters to VO SQL transient attribute

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I created a view object for scott.emp table
I added a transient attribute, then change the default value to be from SQL and wrote statement like this:

select max(nvl(sal, 0)) from emp where deptno = view.deptno

my problem is: how to pass view.deptno as parameter to sql statement ?

running the page ,I have got an error.

ORA-00904: "EMP_VO"."DEPTNO": invalid identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your VO's query, it should looks similar to this:

SELECT Emp.EMPNO, 
       Emp.ENAME, 
       Emp.JOB, 
       Emp.MGR, 
       Emp.HIREDATE, 
       Emp.SAL, 
       Emp.COMM, 
       **Emp.DEPTNO**,
       (select max(nvl(sal, 0)) from emp where deptno = **Emp.DEPTNO**)
FROM EMP Emp

Comment: the result is not true, the where clause deptno = Emp.Deptno is eventuated  as where 1=1

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by inspiration from previous answer, as I wrote in sql field in Default values the following clause by using Entity attribute so it works.

```
select max(nvl(sal, 0)) from emp where deptno = Emp_EO.DEPTNO
```

In my first post I used View object attribute in where clause, but this throws above error ORA-00904.

the condition values in where clause must be entity attribute not view attribute.

```
 Emp_EO.DEPTNO
```